# How does FiddlerCore decrypt HTTPS traffic

Tags: c#, windows, fiddlercore

I wrote a little program for capture https traffic. I want to capture **DECODED** get and post data using that software.
As you know, the Fiddler application can do that like a charm and now i am looking for a way to do that in my program.

For instance, here's my code:

```
   void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Fiddler.Session oSession)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                oSession.bBufferResponse = true;
                txtLog.Text += "full-url : \r\n" + oSession.fullUrl.ToString() + "\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\n";
                txtLog.Text += "method : \r\n" + oSession.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod + "\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\n";
                txtLog.Text += "request headers : \r\n" + oSession.oRequest.headers + "\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\n";
                txtLog.Text += "responce headers : \r\n" + oSession.oResponse.headers + "\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\n";
                txtLog.Text += "get request body as string : \r\n" + oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString() + "\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\n";
                txtLog.Text += "request body bytes : \r\n" + oSession.requestBodyBytes + "\r\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\r\n";

                txtLog.SelectionStart = txtLog.Text.Length;
                txtLog.ScrollToCaret();
            }));
        }
```

and `get request body as string` in `txtLog` for an https web page is like below :

```
get request body as string : 
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Major Version: 3
Minor Version: 1
Random: 52 02 18 75 64 2D 8D 65 75 B9 C4 1B 58 76 92 3E 6B C5 BF 1D 3B D4 53 5D D2 FA CA D8 BF CE 02 5D
SessionID: empty
Ciphers: 
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
```

what is this handshake part and how can i decode it?
as you know there are two files (TrustCert.exe & makecert.exe) inside installed fiddler application.
what are these files and can i use them inside my little application for decoding data? how?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler2.com/core/) class library decrypts HTTPS traffic using a man-in-the-middle approach.

As discussed in the [Fiddler book](http://fiddlerbook.com):

> The HTTPS protocol sandwiches an encrypted (SSL or TLS) connection
> between HTTP requests and the underlying TCP/IP network connection
> upon which those requests are sent. Network intermediaries or
> observers are thus prevented from viewing or modifying the HTTP
> traffic thanks to the use of the cryptographic protocols.  You might
> then be surprised to learn that Fiddler can both view and modify HTTPS
> traffic if configured appropriately. Fiddler achieves this by using a
> “man-in-the-middle” approach to HTTPS, which means that when talking
> to the client, it pretends to be the server, and when talking to the
> server, it pretends to be the client.
>
> The HTTPS protocol is explicitly designed to block this attack by using digital certificates
> to authenticate the identity of a HTTPS server (and optionally the
> client). When a client receives a certificate from the server, it
> validates that the certificate itself is trustworthy by determining
> whether it is chained to a Root Certification Authority that is
> trusted by the client or the operating system. Since you are typically
> running Fiddler on your own computer, you can reconfigure your browser
> or operating system to trust Fiddler’s root certificate. After you do
> so, the client application will not complain when it detects that
> traffic is being protected by Fiddler-generated certificates.

If your goal is to embed this capability into your application, you should simply use FiddlerCore in your application-- that's why it exists!

As to your question about the "handshake"-- the handshake is how the client and the server agree on the parameters for the HTTPS communication (e.g. what cipher and keys to use). You don't "decode" the handshake per-se-- FiddlerCore handles this for you.

You might be getting confused because HTTPS traffic runs inside a HTTP `CONNECT` tunnel, and that tunnel is also visible in FiddlerCore. To ensure that your HTTPS Sessions are also captured, be sure to pass the `FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL` flag when calling the `Startup` method. Also, be sure that `makecert.exe` is in the same folder as your program's executable.

Also, keep in mind that setting the `bBufferResponse` property *after* the Session has already completed processing has no effect; you should remove that.

Comment: thanks eric for your comprehensive answer, so your answer tell us we can have DECODED requests + responces in our application (like LIVE HTTP HEADERS add-on for FIreFox) and there is no need decryption by us.am i right?

Comment: Your software doesn't need to decrypt anything; FiddlerCore itself does decryption when you set the DecryptSSL flag.